# Eclipse: How to find the type of the variable in Expressions window?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse includes a window named "Expressions" that allows showing the content of expressions/variables. My problem is that I can't see the Type/Class expressions window.

[image]

Do you know how I can use the Expressions window to see the type of the result of the expressions?

Comment: Are you talking about the debug perspective?

Comment: yes. Debug Perspective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **view menu** of the *Expressions* view select ***Layout > Select Columns...*** and check ***Declared Type*** or/and ***Actual Type***:

[image]