# How to get definition of a SimpleName?

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

Here is my setting code

```
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
    parser.setSource(content.toCharArray());
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    String[] sourcepathEntries = { folderPath };
    String[] encodings = { "UTF-8" };
    parser.setEnvironment(null, sourcepathEntries, encodings, true);
    parser.setUnitName(filePath);
    parser.setStatementsRecovery(true);  
    CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
```

The test file is

```
public class A {
    B b = new B();
    C c = new C();
    int name = 15;
    public void run() {
        int x = 25;
        int d = x + 10;
        if (x != 25) {
            d = 99;
        }
        System.out.println(d);
    }

    public B getB() {
        b.run();
        return b;
    }
}
```

[My debug code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg3gz.png)

I have already get the `Ibinding` from `SimpleName.resolveBinding()` but I can't get any field information from `IBinding binding`. I am surprised that `binding instanceof VaribleBinding` return `false` although debug view shows that.
I can see the `LocalDeclaration` but I can not get it. Can anyone help me to solve this? Or provide an alternative solution.

Comment: To find out the actual type of `binding`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47310164/6505250

Comment: The `LocalVariableBinding` you are looking at in the screenshot is "none of your business", its the compiler's internal representation, not API. What you should be interested in is the `binding` that is not fully visible in the screenshot. When you say "get definition", would the `IVariableBinding` be sufficient for your task, or do you need to find the corresponding `VariableDeclarationStatement` AST node (the DOM equivalent of the internal `LocalDeclaration` you are referring to)?

Comment: In fact, I need to get corresponding `ASTNode` for my task. I need to get `LocalDeclaration` from `LocalVariableBinding` or `MethodDeclaration` with `MethodBinding`. For `LocalVariableBinding` I can modify source code to get `LocalDeclaration` but for `MethodBinding` I don't know how to get `MethodDeclaration`. @StephanHerrmann

Comment: To get AST for the declaration of a given binding, strategy differs if you already know that the element is within the current compilation unit vs. the case where you first have to find the other compilation unit. Which matches you use case - same CU or different?

Comment: Other CU. In fact, I know how to solve this. First, I use `createASTs` to generate `ASTs`.The I can find a internal class `BindingResolver` to find declaration.@StephanHerrmann